# Firebase deregistering Push-Tokens without me wanting it

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've created a Firebase instance on my Android app and got a Push-Token through that (`cH5IfGPuK9M:APA...`).

I send a Push-Message to the device with that Push-Token receiving this answer:

```
{"multicast_id":8657342075440110655,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1482349908271867%e3e016aee3e016ae"}]}
```

`"success"` is `1` so the message got delivered. I see that message on my phone also.

Then, after I closed my app and opened it again, I send more notifications and always get a result of `"success":0` and `"failure":1`.

Heres the Data I've send in that case:

```
{ "notification": { "title": "http://10.0.0.10:5000/Controller/Function?ParameterID=3", "body": "YOURE FIRED!"  }, "to": "d_NyMcrnuN8:APA91b..." }
```

And the Result:

```
{"multicast_id":6277800736366672436,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

(Ive anonymized the actual contents and shortened the tokens here)

What do I need to do to maintain the push-token? For some reason its unregistering when closing.

Comment: Can you post the exact response for the `"failure":1` error? Relevant codes and a sample payload would also help.

Comment: Hello, yes I added an example for the send data and also a "failure":1 result.